# XAML in Database - Getting Very Meta

Tags: .net, wpf, database, xaml, metadata

How would you go about making an application that can edit it's own look and feel?
Can tweak its own XAML files? then reload them. I'm thinking a notepad-like text editor, not a visual designer.

All the event/code would be bound right after display from an "iron" scripting language.

Comment: Sounds like some kind of twisted nightmare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this anyway you want, just **completely abstract the display engine from all other logic** including event bindings and what not. The data-format for the UI be it XAML or even an executed JavaScript blob then doesn't matter.. what matters is the engine can provide a **consistent interface** for passing events back to the logic, regardless of the UI state.

To do this you could create a **self modifying engine that uses an engine definition to construct an engine for self-modifying UI definitions** :P

Comment: How about if you just had XAML in the database that was more like a document (rather than a true GUI interface). How does the WPF engine display XAML in XAML? What control or mechanism?

Comment: XAML in XAML ...? XAML into an engine that can reload the XAML definition, display the UI it defines and re-hookup the events and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a few prototypes where I put a XAML document on a web server and download that XAML and load it into an ElementHost control on a WinForm form.  It worked quite well.

I have not tried hooking up event handlers yet though.

Update:
[This](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/03/xaml-events-in-compiled-and-uncompiled-scenarios.aspx) blog post by Rob Relyea has more information that you could ever want to know about hooking up events to downloaded XAML.

Comment: I would recommend some kind of abstraction of events and handlers such that the logic side maintains a hashtable of virtual events and handlers that the UI can bridge to.